# modify method only having the method's name and instance object

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I know with `getattr()` you can call the method, but I need to overwrite it, so `myInstance.mymethod` will be overwritten.

I have the method's name as a string and the instance's reference.

Comment: What do you want to replace it *with*?

Comment: another function, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite it with `setattr`

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def method(self): pass
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.method()
>>> setattr(a,'method',1)
>>> a.method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

To replace with another method:

```
>>> import types
>>> setattr(a,'method',types.MethodType(lambda self: self.__class__.__name__,a))
>>> a.method()
'Foo'
```

Where the lambda stuff is just fancy shorthand for defining a function:

```
def func(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__

setattr(a,'method',types.MethodType(func,a))
```